# Move border-less window.

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a borderless program in WPF. How can I move my program with click, holding and moving the mouse? 
My form just have a picture background.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. You Question is very Vague and it is not perfect. I recommend you to read this article first [what-have-you-tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) it will help you to ask a more detailed question. By the way: What have you Tried?

Comment: Hi, My problem is that i can't move my border-less program

Comment: My suggestion would be to always try to find a solution first yourself (Google is a good starting point) then come here with an example of what you tried that is how this site works best in my eyes and you also learn more if you do it yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XAML, place this event handler for your window's `MouseDown` event:

```
<Window MouseDown="Window_MouseDown">
    ...
</Window>
```

In the code-behind, place this:

```
private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.DragMove();
}
```